# Export all YouTube watch history

Tags: youtube, export

I'd like to export all of my YouTube watch history.

It seems to exist if I use the YouTube history page, but it requires me to keep scrolling down and clicking "Load more"; besides, using the resulting source does not, from what I see, contain access time and date. Neither does Google Takeout provide the entire history.

Is there a better way, perhaps via API?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a scraper (in Python 2.7 and Scrapy) for this task a while ago. Sans official API, it uses a logged-in session cookie and HTML parsing. Dumps to SQLite by default. [GitHub: YouTube Watch History Scraper](https://github.com/zvodd/Youtube-Watch-History-Scraper)